# How to parse multipart/form-data forwarded by Mailgun API on AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, multipartform-data, serverless-framework, mailgun

Here is what I am trying to achieve: Users will be able to email me at test@myDomain.com which is integrated with the Mailgun service. Based off a rule I'll have set Mailgun will forward this email as a POST request to https:url-to-my-lambda-function.amazonaws.com/email. I then receive this POST request in Lambda, parse it, then grab and use the html from the email for further work.

**The issue I am running into is that Mailgun sends their POSTs not as JSON but as a multipart/form-data.** I have not been able to find a way to parse this content type and grab the email html. Here is a [sample](http://bin.mailgun.net/ec2835ad#8zg7) forwarded email from Mailgun (note that technically mailgun sends along attachments too, but all I care about is the stripped-html field).

Also note that I am working with the Serverless framework and need to write this function in either Python or Node.js.

**Things I have tried to do to parse the POST request:**

- Tried using the [parse-multipart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart) npm library, but was unable to get it to work I think because I couldn't find the boundary string. This might still be a tenable solution.
- Tried `let body = new String(decodeURIComponent(event.body));` , to put the data into a string and decode it because it seemed to be coming in URL encoded. Then I was using regex to find and pull out the stripped-html that I wanted. However, I think the URL decoding wasn't properly working because it was converting spaces into pluses. See the block below as an example of what I got:

```
<td+align="center"+valign="top"+id="m_-6910385412628668961m_-3845437051063103019m_-3682438291175620773bodyCell"+style="padding-bottom:40px;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;border-top:0">\n++++++++++++++++++++++++\n++++++++++++++++++++++++<table+border="0"+cellpadding="0"+cellspacing="0"+width="100%"+style="border-collapse:collapse">\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<tbody><tr>\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<td+align="center"+valign="top">\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<table+border="0"+cellpadding="0"+cellspacing="0"+width="100%"+id="m_-6910385412628668961m_-3845437051063103019m_-3682438291175620773templatePreheader"+style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#eaeaea;border-top:0;border-bottom:1px+solid+#d0d0d0">\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<tbody><tr>\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\t<td+align="center"+valign="top">\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<table+border="0"+cellpadding="0"+cellspacing="0"+width="600"+style="border-collapse:collapse">
```

- I have also tried using libraries like [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) to decode the multipart/form-data but have had issues with getting them working in Lambda because they work off of requests.

How can I parse this POST request? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider using a module designed to parse multipart form data such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-formdata.

Comment: Thanks. Considering that it is in a Lambda function though, what do I pass in to the library as a request? Lambda doesn't give me a request object, all I have is the event with a body in string form.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_request_object.htm

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean? Are you suggesting I spoof a request object with the event information Lambda gives me and then hand it to the NPM library?